# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, jpa

I have this strange error when deploying my application , but the jar needed is in my POM file !!!

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Here the error:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [fr/telecom/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder
```

I even check the war and the jar is inside the war

[image]

Searching  Ctrl + Shift + T I found:

```
org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.MetaDataBuilder
```

and

```
org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError isn't saying that class is not present. It's saying a dependency of that class is not found in the CLASSPATH. So look at the source for that class and see what it needs

Comment: Also depending on your IDE and project setup, you may need to execute some sort of "refresh" operation.  In some projects with multiple pom files, for example, a rebuild of the full project would be required to fix dependency issues.

Comment: When you do a `Ctrl + Shift + T` (Open Type) in your Eclipse and search for `MetadataBuilder`, how many do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version. `org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder` is available in version 5:

```
$ jar tvf ~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.4.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.4.Final.jar | grep MetadataBuilder

3931 Wed Nov 18 12:22:14 CET 2015 org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder.class
```

In version `4.3.6.Final`, it's defined in another package:

```
$ jar tvf ~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar | grep MetadataBuilder

672 Wed Jul 16 16:28:14 CEST 2014 org/hibernate/metamodel/MetadataBuilder.class
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The head of you DTD in hibernate.config.xml must be the following:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"classpath:/org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

`

2) if you have you hibernate.config.xml in /WEB-INF remove it and place in /src/main/resources;

3) Finally, you will have to ovewrite some lines in web.xml file where you invoke the hibernate to be as the following:

```
`<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>   
        classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml                     
        </param-value>
    </context-param>`
```

I Hope it halps. Herman, Mozambique